# How to implement a generic button class that executes different functions on click?

Tags: c++, button, sdl

Okay, I'm using **SDL with C++** and I started working on a simple GUI for my Map Editor. From a working prototype of a single button, I wrote a generic GUIObject class and a generic Button class. But I have a problem now, In order for the class to be reusable, I need to be able to set for each button what function it calls (i.e. **Help!** opens the help window, **Open** opens the file dialog box, they are the same Button class, but they execute different functions).

Now, I used some time ago a simple library for Ruby GUI, and it's syntax used something that was notated there as a "block operator":

Example:

```
@login_button = Button.new(@window, 98, 131, Network_Data::LOGIN_BUTTON){execute_login}
```

The last part {} was the thing where you put your own function and the class somehow extracted that and executed that function when clicked. I also heard Java has something similar:

```
onClick = new Function() { }
```

So how would I go and implement this in a C++ program (which uses SDL libraries). I don't want to use any GUI libraries because they seem too complicated and I would have a hard time inserting those libraries in my already built code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using function/functor/method pointers. (functions should be enough and relatively simple)

you can pass a pointer to the callback function in you button constructor.

Here is a basic example using function pointers.

```
class Button
{   
    typedef void(*eventFunction)();

    Button( eventFunction funcPtr ) : m_funcPtr( funcPtr ){}
    ///< A constructor.
    /// @param funcPtr The function pointer to register.

    ~Button(){ m_funcPtr = NULL; }
    ///< A destructor.          

    void operator() () const
    {
        (m_funcPtr)();
    }
    ///< Invokes the registered function.

    private:
        eventFunction m_funcPtr;
};
```

And you can use it this way:

```
void myFunction1() { /* do something */ }
void myFunction2() { /* do something else */ }

Button myButton1( &myFunction1 );
myButton1(); // invoke the function registered

Button myButton2( &myFunction2 );
myButton2(); // invoke the function registered
```

---

Here is a more complex example using variadic templates (C++0x)

```
template < class Tr, class... Args >
class Button
{
    typedef Tr(*eventFunction)(Args...);

    Button( eventFunction funcPtr ) : m_funcPtr( funcPtr ){}
    ///< A constructor.
    /// @param funcPtr The function pointer to register.

    ~Button(){ m_funcPtr = NULL; }
    ///< A destructor.          

    void operator() ( Args&... args ) const
    {
        (m_funcPtr)(args...);
    }
    ///< Invokes the registered function with the provided arguments.
    /// @param args The arguments to transmit to the invoked function.

    private:
        eventFunction m_funcPtr;
};
```

And you can use it this way:

```
void myFunction1( int, double ) { /* do something */ }
void myFunction2() { /* do something */ }

Button<void, int, double> myButton1( &myFunction1 );
myButton1( 10, 20.5 );  // invoke the function registered with two arguments

Button<void> myButton2( &myFunction2 );
myButton1(); // invoke the function registered without argument
```

The `Tr` template can be removed and replaced by `void` if you never plan to use others functions than functions returning void.

Thus `Button<void, int, double> myButton1( &myFunction1 );` would change to `Button<int, double> myButton1( &myFunction1 );`

and `Button<void> myButton2( &myFunction2 );` would change to `Button<> myButton2( &myFunction2 );`

---

You can do almost the same thing with methods (you need to register a pointer to the instance of the class to call AND the pointer to the method) and with functors (you need to register a pointer to the instance of the functor to call).

---

On your demand here is the same class to do it with methods. It's up to you to find a way to make your Button class accept functions, functors and methods at once (think virtual ^^). This is the C++0x version

```
template < class C, class Tr, class... Args >
class Button
{
    typedef Tr(C::*eventMethod)(Args...);
    ~Button(){}

    Button( C& target, eventMethod method ) : m_target(target), m_method(method) {}
    ///< A constructor.
    /// @param target The class member instance used to call the method.
    /// @param method The class member method pointer to register.

    bool operator () ( Args&... args ) const
    {
        (m_target.*(m_method))(args...);
    }
    ///< Invokes the registered method with the provided arguments.
    /// @param args The arguments to transmit to the invoked method.

    private:
        eventMethod m_method;
        C& m_target;
};
```

And you can use it this way:

```
class MyClass
{
    void method1(){};
    void method2( int, double ){};
};

MyClass myC1;

Button<MyClass, void> myButton1( myC1, &MyClass::method1 );
myButton1(); // invoke the registered method using the registered class instance.

Button<MyClass, void, int, double> myButton2( myC1, &MyClass::method2 );
myButton2( 15, 170.5 ); // invoke the registered method using the registered class instance.
```

If you need to call it from inside the class the method belong to, use `this` as target parameter instead of `myC1`.

Comment: Ah this looks nice and I can mostly understand your examples, so I'll try to implement this in my code and I choose this as my preffered answer. Only one more question, why did you need to add void as the first argument in the complex example?

Comment: This is the "Tr" template value, the return type of the function you point to. In my example I do not return anything, but the operator() could return the value returned by the functions you point to... I modified my answer to explain how to remove it if needed. Be sure to consider that the second one needs C++0x.

Comment: Thank you again greatly, you actually took the time to write a longer example!

Comment: How would that example look like with a method, and if I initialize the Button inside the same class? I have a class called Engine, initialized button as: Button<void> Button_Test( &ChangePassability() ); and ChangePassability is a public member function of Engine.

Comment: Added, and the second answer is "this". I'm back to my bug now ;)

Comment: Sadly it does not work, it says missing template arguments. I tried putting <void, void> (as now it needs 2), but it says "error: creating pointer to member function of non-class type 'void'"

Comment: Ah, that's my fault, I will edit the way to use it. My example should be <void>. "C" is the class type "MyClass", and you already informs this C value when writing &MyClass::method1 as second parameter. So you only need to tell about the return types and the arguments types, not about the class type.

Comment: "error: missing template arguments before 'myButton1'" - It seems it wants the template arguments in the same position they were.

Comment: Err... you are right (sorry my mind is on another problem), using this approach you have to define <MyClass, void>

Comment: Works now. Thumbs up! You deserve 10 gold medals for this, thank you. Oh, except example should be Button<MyClass, void> myButton1( myC1, &MyClass::method1 ); instead of Button myButton1<MyClass, void>( myC1, &MyClass::method1 );

Comment: Haha you are right once again ;). That's edited, thank you. I will come back later to reorganize this answer for incoming readers...

Comment: Okay, I have just one more issue, I integrated everything, but I have functions inside Button class, for instance OnRender() which draws each button according to it's attributes. The problem is that I get an error when compiling on those functions: "error: 'template<class C, class Tr, class ... Args> class Button' used without template parameters". I have a header for it and a cpp file with the functions http://pastebin.com/2HEUM5K0 how do I need to edit my button classes functions to make it work correctly with your edits?

Comment: As this is a template class, I think you need to define your function **inside the .h file** directly. If you define your function inside the class nothing more should be needed, but if you define the function outside the class brackets (still inside .h through), you need to remember the function the template informations: `template <class C, class Tr, class... Args> void Button<C,Tr,Args...>::OnRender(SDL_Surface* Src_Dest, SDL_Surface* Surf_Button) {...}`

Comment: One last thing and then I got it all set up, how can I call the function if I pass the reference to the Button into an array? I do it so I can do this genericly for all registered buttons at once:
http://pastebin.com/MBLQJEwt
Fisrt part are the classes, the snippet is the inclusion into the array, and the last one is my for array that loops trough all buttons.

Comment: Humm `(*GUIObject::ObjectList[i])();` should work i guess. Or `(GUIObject::ObjectList[i])();` but I think the first one is the good one.

Comment: First one says: "no match for call to '(GUIObject) ()'" while the second one throws "cannot be used as a function". First one seems right, but it doesn't work quite properly. Also, the function I registered to it is a void function with no arguments, so that's not causing the error.

Comment: I didn't seen it earlier, but you can't as you store GUIObject pointers in your vector instead of Button classes, and as GUIObject have no operator() methods it can't work with the parenthesis overload.
You must define a `virtual bool operator () ( Args&... args ) const = 0;` in your GUIObject, but if you do so, you need to add template to the GUIObject class.

Comment: Can you please add an example for that? I have no experience in these class templates...

Comment: I tried with a templated GUIObject class, and the correct way to call the method from inside the for loop is as follow : `(*GUIObject<>::ObjectList[i])();` `(*GUIObject<int>::ObjectList[i])();` etc. depending on the buttons type.

Comment: Here is an example of GUIObject using the virtual operator and templates : http://pastebin.com/h4uEbwSg . As you can see it make it much more less generic. So YES you can keep it more generic by storing the vector(s) in the button(s). Each button type will then have it's own static vector for all the buttons waiting for the same arguments. This is probably not the best approach though, but this is how we learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. You can use run-time polymorphism (`boost::function` or `std::tr1::function` or `std::function`) or you can use a template.

Answer (score 0):

You will need your button class to call functions specified by its users. I recommend you to take a look at [Boost Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/signals.html) library. That library implements signals and slots approach, has very nice documentation and is very well supported. Also, these links should be useful to get the general idea:

- [Signals and slots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots)
- [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
- [Callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It works in almost the same way in c++ as you'd use in java:

```
onClick = new ClickFunction;
```

but then you'd obviously need the following to define necessary classes:

```
template<class A, class B>
class Function { public: virtual B Map(A a) const=0; };

Function<int, int> *onClick;

class ClickFunction : public Function<int,int>
{
public:
    ClickFunction(MyObject &o) : o(o) { }
    int Map(int a) const { return 10; }
private:
    MyObject &o;
};
```

Comment: So with this, I would just add your code, set onClick and then pass it as an argument (i.e. Button(x,y,width,height,function)?